# Batch-I want to set second part of variable

Tags: batch-file, if-statement, command

I have a problem.

```
set /p command=  
if %command% == "display (i want the second part of the variable here)" echo (second part of the variable)
```

For example, i type:

```
display hello
```

I want it to simply:

```
echo hello
```

I want to use this for custom commands in my game.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, you can split the text on firstword|notfirstword with a `for /f` loop using `"tokens=1*"`.  See `help for` in a console window for full details.

Next, you could use attempt to `call :label` where `:label` is whatever the first word was.  In essence, you're creating [batch functions](http://www.dostips.com/DtTutoFunctions.php) and letting the user choose which function is executed.  If the function label doesn't exist, then errorlevel will be non-zero and you can handle appropriately using [conditional execution](http://www.dostips.com/?t=Snippets.ConditionalExecution).  This makes it easy to expand your script without having to add an `if /i` statement for each choice or synonym you add.  (It might be a good idea to hide the error message for attempting to `call` a non-existent label by redirecting `2>NUL`.)  Here's a full example:

```js
@echo off & setlocal

:entry
set /P "command=Command? "

for /f "tokens=1*" %%I in ("%command%") do (
    2>NUL call :%%I %%J || (
        if errorlevel 1000 (exit /b 0) else call :unsupported %%I
    )
    goto :entry
)

:display
:echo
:say
:show
echo(%*
exit /b 0

:ping
ping %~1
exit /b 0

:exit
:quit
:bye
:die
echo OK, toodles.
exit /b 1000

:unsupported <command>
1>&2 echo %~1: unrecognized command
exit /b 0
```